# Foreach loop inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I have a list of names and each name consist of **2-4 words**: name, (if exist) middle name(s), surname.

These are the names:

- Ali Yilmaz
- Taha Ugur Unal
- Omer Ibrahim Tahsin Son
- Recai Sahin

etc.

I want to print this names as this: **Surname, name middle name(s) (if exist)**

The names above will be:

- Ali Yilmaz -> **Yilmaz, Ali**
- Taha Ugur Unal -> **Unal, Taha Ugur**
- Omer Ibrahim Tahsin Son -> **Son, Omer Ibrahim Tahsin**
- Recai Sahin -> **Sahin, Recai**

etc.

If I had only one name I can use that code:

```
    <?php $exp1 = explode(" ", $author1); ?>        
    <?php if (count($exp1) == 2) {?>
    <?php print ($exp1[1] .', ' .$exp1[0]); ?>

    <?php } elseif (count($exp1) == 3) {?>
    <?php print ($exp1[2] .', ' .$exp1[0] .' ' .$exp1[1]); ?>

    <?php } elseif (count($exp1) == 4) {?>
    <?php print ($exp1[3] .', ' .$exp1[0] .' ' .$exp1[1] .' ' .$exp1[2]); ?>        

    <?php }?>
```

Each page can have different numbers of author and I thought I could use foreach to apply the above code for each author name but I couldn't do this.

I tried a piece of code such that:

```
        <?php foreach $author as $obj): ?>
            <?php $a = explode (" ", $obj) ?> 
        <?php endforeach ?>
        ...
```

But it gives error:

> explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given.

How can I do this?

Comment: why you close your php each line?

Comment: Please do a `var_dump` of `$obj`) immediately within the outer `foreach` and post the results so we can investigate.

Comment: @vp_arth because it's about Drupal structure (https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards).

Comment: @Dai, this the results:
Array array(2) { ["tid"]=> string(4) "5930" ["taxonomy_term"]=> object(stdClass)#117 (8) { ["tid"]=> string(4) "5930" ["vid"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(22) "Çiğdem Apaydın Kaya" ["description"]=> NULL ["format"]=> NULL ["weight"]=> string(1) "0" ["vocabulary_machine_name"]=> string(5) "yazar" ["rdf_mapping"]=> array(5) { ["rdftype"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "skos:Concept" } ["name"]=> array(1) { ["predicates"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "rdfs:label" [1]=> string(14) "skos:prefLabel" } } ["description"]=> array(1) { ["predicates"]=> array(1) { ...

Comment: This `Coding Standards` never say to do this)

Comment: @herci it looks like `$obj` is not a simple string-value then. You'll need to extract the right value from `$obj` first before passing it into `explode`.

Comment: You are missing a `(` in your `foreach` statement. Also, there is a `;` after `endforeach`.

Comment: @Dai, thanks a lot... I completely forgot that.

Comment: @CEP, in the actual code these exist, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$names = array(
  'Ali Yilmaz',
  'Taha Ugur Unal',
  'Omer Ibrahim Tahsin Son',
  'Recai Sahin'

);

// First you should iterate through:
foreach ($names as $name) {
  // and now, let make the job
  // split by words
  $parts = explode(' ', $name);
  if (count($parts) == 1) {
    echo "{$name}<br/>";
    continue;
  }
  // get last word
  $last = array_pop($parts);
  // Print last one, comma, and rest of name
  echo "{$last}, " . implode(' ', $parts) . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: @RajibGhosh, no, error-free code not exists at all :)

Comment: and good  job @vp_arth...i am trying to updated your code ...if you have any problem i can remove my updated code ...if you want. i am open..and now i think your code is ok.

Comment: I've not any problem) it is not a contest

Answer (score 1):

If you had a single string, you would

- split all the words with `explode()`.
- take out the surname and store it.
- join the rest of the name with `implode()`.

See the example below:

```
<?php

$name = "Son of the Mask";
$words = explode(" ", $name);  // split the string wherever there is a whitespace.
$surname = array_pop($words);
$restOfTheName = implode(" ", $words);  // join the words with a whitespace in between them.

echo $surname . ", " . $restOfTheName;

?>
```

On the other hand, if you have a list of names in an array called, say, `$namelist`, you can use the `foreach()` loop to iterate through the list.

You would do something like:

```
<?php

foreach ($namelist as $name)
{
    $words = explode(" ", $name);
    $surname = array_pop($words);
    $restOfTheName = implode(" ", $words);

    echo $surname . ", " . $restOfTheName;
}

?>
```

Hope that helped `:-)`

---

#### EDIT:

And no, you need not use `<?php` and `?>` on every line. This is only helpful, say when you want to use small snippets of PHP inside your HTML tags.

For example, let us say you want to display some information in an unordered list. Then you would do something like

```
<?php

$info1 = "Head over to Google.com";
$info2 = "Search before you post!";

?>

<ul>
    <li><?php echo $info1; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $info2; ?></li>
</ul>
```

But, doing this for a script that contains only PHP code doesn't make sense. Moreover, it renders your code difficult to read, and eats up a lot of your valuable time.

Comment: Thanks, it's working.

And for your edit, you're right; I'm using some span tags and so I'm using <?php and ?> on every line. As you said I don't need to use for each line, maybe for some of them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

## you can try this

```
   <?php
     $newNameArray=array();
     $namesArray = array(
       'Ali Yilmaz',
       'Taha Ugur Unal',
       'Omer Ibrahim Tahsin Son',
       'Recai Sahin'
     );
    foreach ($namesArray as $name) {

         $partsOfName = explode(" ", $name);
        //last name
        $lastName = array_pop($partsOfName);
        // store the name in new array
       $newNameArray[]=$lastName.", ".implode(" ", $partsOfName);
     }

    //show all names 
    var_dump($newNameArray);
?>
```

you can see this for details [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
foreach ($author as $obj) {
    $nameArr = explode(' ',$obj);
    if(count($nameArr) > 1) {
        $lname = $nameArr[count($nameArr)-1];
        array_pop($nameArr);
        echo $lname.", ".implode(' ',$nameArr);
        echo "<br />";
    } else {
        echo $obj;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```